# C#. Dapper - вставка нескольких элементов и возврат их Id

Tags: c#, dapper

решил потренироваться на тестовой БД вставку нескольких значений в таблицу через Dapper

Postgress 14.0

```
create table actor
(
    actor_id    integer generated always as identity
        constraint actor_pkey
            primary key,
    first_name  varchar(45)             not null,
    last_name   varchar(45)             not null,
    last_update timestamp default now() not null
);

using IDbConnection db = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
db.Open();


const string query = @"INSERT INTO actor(first_name, last_name) VALUES (@first_name, @last_name) RETURNING actor_id;";
var actorList = new List<ActorDal>
{
    new ActorDal {first_name = "Bob", last_name = "Torton"},
    new ActorDal {first_name = "Nikita", last_name = "Mickhalkov"}
};

var insertedIds = await db.QueryAsync<int>(query, actorList);
```

Выскакивает исключение

```
An enumerable sequence of parameters (arrays, lists, etc) is not allowed in this context
```

Если использовать

```
await db.ExecuteAsync(query, actorList);
```

то все нормально.

Но мне нужно получать Id вставленных элементов.

Если вставляю 1 элемент через

```
QueryAsync<int>(query, oneItem)
```

то тоже работает и возвращается Id вставленного элемента.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663184/5045688 - несколько способов

Comment: Спасибо выберу подходящий способ

Comment: Единственное забавно что ответ 2015года и что с того времени проблема элегантно не решена.

Comment: Ну, можно использовать Entity Framework - он сам айдишники из БД получит. Возможно и для Dapper есть расширения, делающие это, просто их найти нужно.

Comment: По поводу расширений, хорошо что напомнили, поищу. EF Постоянно использую, а Dapper только для чтения из БД использовал, благо что это просто методы расширения над коннектом к БД. Тут решил оптимизировать большую вставку за раз и сразу напоролся на трудности). Linq2Db еще хотел посмотреть хотя бы на Pet проекте  каком нибудь

Comment: Можно поступить радикально: использовать для айдишников Guid, создаваемые на клиенте. В этом случае не нужно их получать из БД.

Comment: Обычно так и делаю, но тут БД не моя(.